# Python: Memory error with large Matrix Multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, memory, matrix

I am using Python with Numpy.

I have the following line:

```
H = X*np.linalg.inv(X.T*X)*X.T
```

Where X is a 220000 by 1 numpy.matrix() object.

I am using Python 64 bit, and getting a Memory error when I attempt to do the above calculation.
Is there a more efficient way to write that line to enable a matrix of this size to be used - or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: The middle part is a scalar inversion, so you can simply write `X*(1/(X.T.dot(X)))*X.T` but still the resulting matrix is 220000 by 220000. Do you have the resources for storing that matrix? It has 50 billion entries

Comment: Thanks for your response. The new code looks much neater.
Evidently not enough storage - a basic PC with ~16GB RAM. I didn't even think of computing the number of elements. I take it that means I'm resource locked unless I can access a PC with much more RAM - Absent of writing the matrix to hard drive and recalling? Or does Python have a library for this sort of large-computation?

Comment: *"...a PC with much more RAM..."*: `H` requires over 380 gigabytes of RAM! Do you really need to compute it explicitly?  `X * X.T / (X.T * X)` is a rank-1 projection matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28linear_algebra%29).  Each column is simply a scalar multiple of `X`.  If `y` is a column matrix, `p = H * y` is equivalent to projecting `y` onto `X`.  That can be computed as `u = X / np.linalg.norm(X); p = u*(u.T*y)`.

Comment: Thanks @WarrenWeckesser, No I don't need it explicitly, I'm trying to get the Standard Errors of the coefficients in an OLS regression:
`H = X*(1/(X.T.dot(X)))*X.T ;
SSe = Y*(np.identity(H.shape[0])-H)*Y.T ;
MSe = SSe/(n-k) ;
std_errors = np.sqrt(np.multiply(MSe, np.linalg.inv(X.T*X)))`

I assume there's a more efficient way to do this then?

Comment: Never, never and never compute an inverse! Use linsolve instead

Comment: @Matt, I'd avoid reimplementing a standard statistical calculation such as this, and use, say, `statsmodels`:  `from statsmodels.api import OLS; r = OLS(Y, X).fit(); print(r.params, r.bse)`.  (The `bse` attribute of the `RegressionResults` class gives the standard error of the parameters.)

Comment: Thanks to both - much appreciated!